# need gmail like functionailty - jquery autocomplete to include names and email addresses - in string searching

Tags: jquery, search, autocomplete

I recently asked this question and got back a great solution using jquery for autocomplete:

[Need a good way for user to select "To" for email sending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297518/need-a-good-way-for-user-to-select-to-for-email-sending)

The solution was to use this syntax:

```
$("#suggest3").autocomplete(someArray, {
    multiple: true,
    mustMatch: true,
    autoFill: true
```

});

i now have autocomplete on a list of email addresses and i need to take it one step further to map onto gmail like functionality where i include both the "real" name and the email address in the list so users can enter either the name or the email address and it will find the entry:

So the list would look similar to this and the user can search by typing "Firs . . ." or "emailAdd..."

```
"First Last" <emailAddress>   
"First1 Las1t" <emailAddress1>   
"First2 Last2" <emailAddress2>
```

Comment: I needed similar functionality in C#/.NET... see question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539799/autocomplete-email-address-and-or-names-in-c]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wait a second.. Did you look at [the demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/autocomplete/demo/)? I think it already does exactly this. For instance, if I type in "for" or "jap" into the e-mail field, the same person shows up: Fornelia Marconi (with "jap" being part of her e-mail address). Here is the code that enables this.

```
$("#thickboxEmail").autocomplete(emails, {
    minChars: 0,
    width: 310,
    matchContains: true,
    highlightItem: false,
    formatItem: function(row, i, max, term) {
        return row.name.replace(new RegExp("(" + term + ")", "gi"), "<strong>$1</strong>") + "<br><span style='font-size: 80%;'>Email: &lt;" + row.to + "&gt;</span>";
    },
    formatResult: function(row) {
        return row.to;
    }
});
```

The array of name-e-mail pairs looks like this:

```
var emails = [
    { name: "Peter Pan", to: "peter@pan.de" },
    { name: "Molly", to: "molly@yahoo.com" }
];
```

Answer (score 3):

FYI, This "autocomplete" plugin is no longer in development, per a note on the webiste:

> http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/
>
> jQuery plugin: Autocomplete
>
> Note (2010-06-23): This plugin is
>   deprecated and not developed anymore.
>   Its successor is part of jQuery UI,
>   and this migration guide explains how
>   to get from this plugin to the new
>   one. This page will remain as it is
>   for reference, but won’t be updated
>   anymore.

So if you want, you can use the following comparable example from the jQueryUI autocomplete:

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#multiple-remote

I personally prefer jQuery Tools to jQueryUI / but they don't offer an autocomplete plugin at this point... oh well.