# Is there a Jquery plugin that autocompletes an email address?

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [need gmail like functionailty - jquery autocomplete to include names and email addresses - in string searching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300091/need-gmail-like-functionailty-jquery-autocomplete-to-include-names-and-email-ad)

When user types in `xxx`,autocomplete with a list of `xxx@gmail.com,xxx@msn.com` and so on?

Comment: You mean something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300091/need-gmail-like-functionailty-jquery-autocomplete-to-include-names-and-email-ad

Comment: How is it supposed to guess which domain to auto-complete? Literally any domain is capable of receiving email.

Comment: Use an autocomplete which can use an array and build the array (or json I guess) and build it on the fly based on user input and your static list of domains.  Pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var options = ['@gmail.com', '@msn.com', '@yahoo.com'];
$("input#autocomplete").autocomplete({
    source: options
});
$("input#autocomplete").keyup(function() {
    var new_options = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++)
        new_options[i] = $(this).val() + options[i];
    $(this).autocomplete( "option", "source", new_options);
});
```

Look at it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4CFHU/).

Comment: I know there are some inefficiencies here, like calling a global variable from inside a function a lot of times and so on, but this is only illustrative :)